# Artifactory pro v7.30.x fails to start (multiple versions and installation methods)

Tags: artifactory

I am evaluating a self-hosted artifactory installation on a trial license. I followed the official installation instructions for the docker container and the linux archive file. Neither of these installation options are working. The artifactory service fails to start.

I have opened an issue to track the problem: https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-27182

TL;DR; A component fails, a nasty stack trace appears in the logs, and eventually the services stop.

Comment: You are using the Derby DB which is a default one, from the first error, it seems Derby DB was not started correctly. So can you kill all the Artifactory processes as. well as kill the derby process, move this "/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/access/derby" folder to any temp location and try to restart again.

Comment: Moreover, it is an issue with DB connection, do share the exact steps you followed to install it for linux archive?

Comment: @MuhammedKashif My steps were as follows: `curl <url for jfrog-artifactory-pro-7.38.10-linux.tar.gz>` then `tar -xvf  jfrog-artifactory-pro-7.38.10-linux.tar.gz` then `mv <archive> /opt/jfrog` then `bash /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/bin/artifactoryctl`

Comment: Here is about 20 minutes of [logs](https://paste.c-net.org/ThrillsDammit) on a clean install

Comment: After the run (linked above) i do not see a /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/access/derby folder

Comment: May ask what are the resources you have provided to Artifactory? In terms of CPU, Memory and IOPS? Did you check that it meets the minimum requirements?

Comment: @shaibz I have tried several configurations. Mainly a 4 core machine (AMD A10 series) with 10gb memory which seem to satisfy the requirements listed in the [official documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/System+Requirements). I do not see anything mentioned wrt IOPS for artifactory. What are your thoughts?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it on my end, do you have any proxy enabled in the server? 
Can you share the system.yaml file? What is the OS which you are using?

The first issue clearly says that it's related to timeout logging in to the Derby DB which suppose to be pretty fast:
Caused by: org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException: Login timeout exceeded.

Comment: @shaibz I am not touching the system.yaml as it has had no effect on starting the service.  When I did change the yaml file to compare it with the default the is either supplied or generated (depending on the version), the only thing I changed was the min and max memory (to min 2gb max 8gb respectively).

Comment: Note: I am not using a proxy. @shaibz what is your hardware profile?

Comment: perhaps you didn't change the memory correctly?
I use centos 7, 4 CPU and 16 GB and 300 GB and it works fine without changing any settings.

Comment: @shaibz how do you mean "change the memory correctly"? I confirmed my VM had the  amount of memory I mentioned.

Comment: @TaylorSchneider I am not saying it's an amount of memory issue, but maybe misconfiguration of the property/value in the yaml itself.
Can you please paste the system.yaml file and omit relevant credentials? Maybe it will help us progress.

Comment: @shaibz I have not modified the yaml at this point. It's the default yaml created by the installer.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that there is a bug in artifactory. I have traced this back to multiple versions and this issue spans multiple years.

The problem appears to be that artifactory cannot get past the bootstrapping/initialization phase when started with artifactoryctl. At a certain point (around 2-5 minutes in) all the services stop and a pid file is left over, which is bad.

The workaround I have found is that the service can pass this initialization phase only after multiple start/stops (3 to be exact). In other words, we call artifactoryctl start, wait for all failures, then artifactoryctl stop and repeat two more times. On the fourth and final start, we will see the service come online (in about 150 - 190s). From then on, the service will start correctly with one call to artifactoryctl start.

I have not yet looked at the systemd unit file. My guess would be that it has/or could be made to have a number of retries to work around this issue and perhapse this issue does not exist when using the service wrapper.

I have also not yet looked again at the docker container which appears to be failing for the same reason. A workaround off the top of my head would be to modify the entrypoint script. If you were to dockerk exec into the container and try the workaround above it would likely terminate the root process and kill the container.